# Delete entire row if cells in column A is empty or having value "Null". After deleting those rows I need to paste in anather sheet

Tags: excel, vba

can someone help please?

Macro for:

Delete entire row if cells in column A is empty or having value "Null". After deleting those rows I need to paste in anather sheet.

In case, sheet 2 is already having some rows, then these newly deleted rows from sheet 1 needs to be put in below those presents rows from sheet 2.

please give some macro code.

thanks

Comment: Do you want all the empty rows at the bottom of the worksheet also moved to **sheet2?**

Comment: The best way to get macro code is to open your ribbon to View, and select Macro>Record Macro.  Then do the copy and paste you want to execute AS IF IT MET the conditions you want.  Then post that code into your revised question.  We can help make it dynamic and adapt to specific situations from there.

Comment: This is a very common type of question on this site. Some searching will get you something to start with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've created the following sample Sheet1 that I'll use to illustrate the answer to the question.

```
Names:         Sales
Kevin          5
Bill           2
Joe            4
Steve          5

Frank          2
Jerry          9


Casey          5
```

You'll notice Row 6, 9, and 10 are blank.

Sheet two looks like this:

```
Names:       Sales
James        7
Phill        3
```

We need our code to first delete the blank rows on Sheet1, then copy those rows to Sheet2 and put them at the end of the sheet.

```
Sub deleteBlanksAndCopy()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim numRowsSheet1 As Integer

'This code will delete the blanks on sheet1
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    numRowsSheet1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = numRowsSheet1 To 1 Step -1
        If IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 1)) Or .Cells(i, 1) = "" Then
            .Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End With

'This code will move the rows from sheet1 to sheet2
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    numRowsSheet1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    j = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

For i = 1 To numRowsSheet1
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows(j + 1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Value
    j = j + 1
Next i
End Sub
```

Thanks, hopefully that helps.

Comment: Hi Kevin,thanks for the answer and efforts. But something is misunderstood here. what i was looking for is, only rows which we deleted from sheet1 needs to be put in sheet2 not the rows which are left behind in sheet1 after deleting blank rows. How can we achieve that? Please help

Comment: Can we delete rows and then paste them using macro? is it achievable. Do we have to first cut paste/copy paste rows and then delete them ?

Comment: Yes, that's fine. Instead of deleting in the first 'If' block, first copy (using the syntax and flow control for copying to the last row of another sheet shown). Then delete. Make sense? Click the checkbox on my answer!

Comment: HI Kevin, can you please rearrange the code as per my requirement.

Comment: I tried,but I'm not getting how to copy rows and paste them into anther sheet.

Comment: I don't get how to run a loop to copy each record and then paste it into another sheet and then move focus on first sheet and then again copy paste records

Comment: Yes. I'm on a trip but basically think about the operations I've showed you and taylor them to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()  
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer  
Dim numRowsSheet1 As Integer
```

'This code will find the last row in Sheet2

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    j = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
End With
```

'This code will copy rows having blank cell in Column A from sheet1 and will paste them on Sheet2

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    numRowsSheet1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To numRowsSheet1 + 1 Step 1
        If IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 1)) Or .Cells(i, 1) = "" Or .Cells(i, 1) = "Null" Then

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows(j + 1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Value
           j = j + 1

        End If
    Next i
End With
```

'This code will delete the blanks on sheet1

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
   numRowsSheet1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

   For i = numRowsSheet1 + 1 To 1 Step -1
        If IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 1)) Or .Cells(i, 1) = "" Or .Cells(i, 1) = "Null" Then
            .Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```